# get the first tr that contains tds

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery how do I get the first table row that contains `<td>s`

So far my code looks like this but its not working?

```
$('#mytable tr').has('td:first').html();
```

thanks

Comment: The correct usage for .has() is $("#mytable tr").has("td:first").html(); But I'm still not sure it will just select the first table row.

Comment: Before you post code you should at least make sure that it does not contain syntax errors.

Comment: and edits must be 6 characters long, i couldn't edit his code to fix the error. great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the first td's parent.

```
$("#mytable td:first").parent().html();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
$($("#mytable").find('tr')[0]).find('td')
```

In this case you can iterate through rows and fetch the tds

```
$($($("#mytable").find('tr')[0]).find('td')[0]).text()
$($($("#mytable").find('tr')[0]).find('td')[1]).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
$("#mytable td:first ").parents('tr').html();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, jQuery maintains the element indices while selecting them -

```
$('#mytable td').eq(0).parent();
```

So in effect, this will select the first `td` in your table and return the parent, which should be a `tr` element, by convention